# Static classes and global variables

Tags: php, static-variables, fuelphp

I'm using FuelPHP 1.6.1 with a lot of static classes, this seems to work out quite nice. Now I have a Menu generator that loads some data

```
$menu = Menu::generate();
```

It loads some data and stores this in `static::$data`
How would I go for another class to load just that? I'm getting `null` results, probably because I'm doing something wrong, but I dont see what I'm doing wrong at the moment.

Also, yes, the `Menu::$data`  is declared `public static $data`

Any tips?

Using FuelPHP's `Session::set()` does the job, but only after a reload, I need the data straight away in other classes, and loading it again results into double queries (which I dont want)
PHP's `$_SESSION` is not used, nor will be used.

Comment: How are you accessing it? How are you saving it?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, in my way of showing views and menu, `menu::generate()` came **after** the other classes that needed it, put it at the start and using FuelPHP's `Session::set()` did the job